# Fatal exception when reading data from cursor from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor, android-database

In AsyncTask I read database table (one-by-one) like this:

```
Cursor result = database.query("country", new String[] { "_id", "name", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "rightanswer", "time1", "time2", "time3" }, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
result.moveToFirst();
```

Then, I print `result.getColumnCount()` and receive 10.

But when I trying to print data like this:

```
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("name")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("var1")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("var2")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("var3")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("var4")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("rightanswer")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("time1")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("time2")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("time3")));
```

I receive error `AndroidRuntime(8279): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1`

```
AndroidRuntime(8279): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But, when I print only two first columns,

```
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("name")));
 System.out.println(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("var1")));
```

It's fully working.

I have no clue.

**UPDATE:**

```
  String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name, var1, var2,var3,var4,rightanswer, time1,time2,time3);";                 
   db.execSQL(createQuery);
```

Comment: It may the 'var2' is returning null

Comment: show the db.create query

Comment: Which line throws the NPE?

Comment: may be there is no  string value in "var2" column

Comment: Show the entire stack trace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the value

```
result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("var2"))
```

returns is `null`. You can enter debug mode in your IDE and verify that.

Another possibility is that you don't even have a column named `var2` in your database. In that case the `getColumnIndex` will return `null`.

If you provide us more information like your db schema we can help you more.

Comment: I check columns names of course. Then, I checked data and fill every column.